# Amazon AWS EC2 Instance Reboot

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have an Amazon AWS EC2 Instance running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I found that when I used `systemctl reboot` or `shutdown -r now` from the command line, I wasn't able to reconnect, but when I did a reboot from the Amazon EC2 console, it came back up without any issues.

I then uncovered [this in their documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-reboot.html):

> We recommend that you use Amazon EC2 to reboot your instance instead of running the operating system reboot command from your instance.

I've been unsuccessful in finding the "why".

Comment: The rest of that paragraph says " If you use Amazon EC2 to reboot your instance, we perform a hard reboot if the instance does not cleanly shut down within four minutes.". I've never tried rebooting the instance directly, I always use the AWS console.

Comment: I saw that, but it's not performing a hard reboot. I looking for an explanation of why using Amazon EC2 works better.

Comment: Suggest you ask Amazon support. They've defined the way to do things on their platform, you're best off just using it.